# Letters not visible when typing and

Tags: asus

I have a logitech keyboard and for some reason it will not let me type certain letters when typing. can you please advise what i can do so that all the letters will come through

Comment: Have you tried another keyboard?

Comment: Welcome to SU. Start by [editing](https://superuser.com/posts/1773130/edit) the question and adding some basic info - like what's the system, what's the OS, if laptop does it work with the internal kbd, does it work with another kbd, does this happen with all applications, does it work if you plug the keyboard to another USB port and so on. See the [Help](https://superuser.com/help) for [how to write a good question](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Welcome to Superuser. Please edit your question to provide more details. Such as  model of keyboard, OS, what keys do or dont work. Do shift  versions work. Do you get nothing or a different character.

Comment: Basic troubleshooting: do you have the same issue with a different keyboard? If so, the problem is with your computer. If not, you should just replace your keyboard.